# Scraping product URLs under specific ZIP Code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to scrape the product links under ZIP code **08041**. I have written the code to scrape the products without ZIP code but don't know how to scrape and send the request fror the products under **08041**?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import random
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wget
import csv
from fp.fp import FreeProxy


def helloworld(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print ('Status',r.status_code)
    #time.sleep(8)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    post = soup.find_all('a',"name")
    
    for href in post:
        if ( href.get('href')[1] == 'p'):
            href = href.get('href')
            print (href)

def page_counter():
    url1 = "https://soysuper.com/c/aperitivos#products"
    print (url1,'\n')
    helloworld(url1)
    
page_counter()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the back-end end-points to mimic a request with a given zip code.

Note: The cookie is hard-coded but valid for a year.

Here's how:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.105 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Cookie": "soysuper=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--166849121eece159a6fdb0c0fe8341032321d9b1;"
}
with requests.Session() as connection:
    r = connection.get("https://soysuper.com/supermarket?zipcode=08041", headers=headers)
    headers["Request-Id"] = r.headers["Next-Request-Id"]
    headers["Referer"] = "https://soysuper.com/c/aperitivos"
    products_data = connection.get("https://soysuper.com/c/aperitivos?products=1&page=1", headers=headers).json()
    print(products_data["products"]["total"])
```

Output: Total number of products for 08041 zip code.

```
2923
```

What you're effectivly getting is a `JSON` with all the product data for a given page. This is what it looks like in the Network tab.

[image]

Do notice the `pager` key. Use it to "paginate" the API and get more product info.